# Jquery multiple on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html code where on clicking a particular button i want to change the color of a particular html element.

```
<paper-button style="background:blue" class="blue"></paper-button>
<paper-button style="background:red" class="red"></paper-button>
```

this is my script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".blue, .red").click(function(){
            $(".abc").css("background-color", $(".blue, .red").css("background-color"));
        });
    });
    </script>
```

on clicking both the buttons the color of that element changes but changes to blue and doesn't change to red.
When i change my code to

```
<paper-button style="background:red" class="red"></paper-button>
<paper-button style="background:blue" class="blue"></paper-button>
```

in this case the color changes to red irrespective of the button pressed.
How to make sure that the color changes to the button pressed.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/bgm0ydmg/

Comment: thanks for this but is there any way in which i give all my buttons same class and on clicking any of them the background of that particular element changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are taking the background color of the 1st element in the dom, when you do this `$(".blue, .red").css("background-color")` . Take just the background color of the clicked element using `$(this)`:

```
   $(".blue, .red").click(function(){
       $(".abc").css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your HTML element whose background is to be changed is

```
<div class="abc"></div>
```

You can wrap your buttons in another div so that you don't have to bind each element to an onclick method and rather handle parent's onclick method.

```
<div id="colorSelectors">
  <span id="blue">Blue</span>
  <span id="red">Red</span>
  <span id="green">Green</span>
</div>
```

In javascript you can select your elements as follows.

```
const colorSelectors = document.querySelector('#colorSelectors');
const elementABC = document.querySelector('.abc');
```

Add event listener to the parent div.

```
colorSelectors.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

And handle the onclick function as follows

```
function handleClick(e) {
  elementABC.style.backgroundColor = e.target.id;
}
```